# How to pass exact string as parameter in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I have the follow test case :

Some function
    Given some condition
    When I go to "\\path\to\folder"
    Then I don't know

I want to use exact: `**"\\\\path\to\folder"**` as string in my keyword argument
When I use above string, I'm getting escaped value.

I tried to use:

- `r"\\path\to\folder"`
- `'\\path\to\folder'`

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is to use a python raw string and just Evaluate it:

```
${my_string}  Evaluate  r"a\\b"
Log To Console  ${my_string}
```

Answer (score 1):

The backslash is an [escape character](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#escaping) in robot, so to send a backslash you must escape the backslash.

```
When I go to  \\\\path\\to\\folder
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to escape it once again:

```
When I go to \\\\path\\to\\folder
```

Or you can use:

```
When I go to ${/}${/}path${/}to${/}folder
```

which will pass `\\path\to\folder`.